# Express backend dropping data when passed from Angular 5 App

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nodemailer

I am building a little demo app to send emails from a form using Node Mailer. I've connected an Angular 5 app to an Express 4 backend. I am running things very simply, with a server.js express file in my project referencing the angular dist file. I then build the angular app and run the server.

Everything is working fine, and the email even sends, but somehow the express backend is losing the data (or I am just not accessing it correctly). The email sends with "undefined" everywhere that I try to use data.

I fill out form fields for name, phone, email, and address. Then I pull the data into a service and send it to the backend. This is my service in Angular that sends the data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
    headers: any;
    clientInfo = '';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    sendEmail(clientData) {
        console.log(clientData);
        return this.http.post('/send-email', clientData);
    }
}
```

When I send this http post it looks good. The request url is correct, the header is application/json, and the payload data is correct: {name: "John Doe", email: "john@johndoemail.com", phone: "18005555555", message: "test"}

Here is my server.js: (sub in a valid gmail account info where there are x's)

```
 // Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 4300;

// Start server
app.listen(port, function(req, res) {
    console.log('Server is running at port: ', port);
})

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Home route to serve the index file
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/send-email', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user:'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
            pass: 'xxxxxxxx',
        }
    });

    let message = {
        from: 'mailer@nodemailer.com',
        to: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
        subject: 'New Client Message ' + req.body.name,
        text: 'Name: ' + req.body.name + '\nEmail: ' + req.body.email + '\nPhone: ' + req.body.phone + '\n    ' + req.body.message,
        html: '<p>' + req.body.message + '</p>'     
    };

    transporter.sendMail(message);
    res.json(req.body);
});
```

In the server console req.body shows up as "{}".
Using my own email, I get a message sent from nodemailer, but all of the data used simply says "undefined".

Do I need to access the data differently? Maybe use another property of req? Anyway, it looks like the issue is in my express file, so let me know if you see any issues there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I was not implementing a header with my post data. I added these changes to my service and the issue was resolved:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
    httpHeader = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        })
    };

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    sendEmail(clientData) {
        console.log(clientData);
        this.http.post('/send-email', clientData, this.httpHeader);
    }
}
```

If you want to see the full demo look here: https://github.com/xTumulus/NodeMailer_AngularExpress_Demo

Comment: at last am very happy to see your thread. could pls share your github repo.. i need to refer how to send mail from front end angular 5 +  nodemailer. i have no idea how to get start

Comment: Yep, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: You have github Repo?

Comment: I added it to the answer as I stated in my last comment. It is the link at the bottom of this answer before the comments.